# Chain Rule twice (second order condition for optimality)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, chain-rule

While studying nonlinear programming (more specifically, second order conditions for optimality), I came across the following:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $d, x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Also, let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that:

$$g(\alpha):=f\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right)$$

The first derivative of $g$ with respect to $\alpha$ equals (by the chain rule):

$$
g^{\prime}(\alpha)=\nabla f\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) \cdot d
$$

Now, what I would like is to differentiate again with respect to $\alpha$ to obtain the following expression (**stuck here**):

$$
g^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)=\sum_{i, j=1}^{n} f_{x_{i} x_{j}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{i} d_{j}
$$

**Attempt:**

What I tried doing to make things easier was to consider $n = 2$ and change notation a little bit. In such case, when differentiating for the first time, we would have:

$$
\left \langle (f_{x_{1}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right), f_{x_{2}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right)),\left(d_{1}, d_{2}\right)\right\rangle
$$

Now, I tried differentiating $$
f_{x_{1}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{1}+f_{x_{2}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{2}
$$

with respect to $\alpha$ using the product rule and the chain rule, resulting in:

$$
f_{x_{1}x_{1}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{1} + f_{x_{2}x_{2}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{2}
$$

which is ALMOST:
$$
g^{\prime \prime}(\alpha)=\sum_{i, j=1}^{2} f_{x_{i} x_{j}}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right) d_{i} d_{j}
$$

I just cannot figure out where does $d_{j}$ comes from, which is the missing term. It is very likely that it came from the chain rule. However, I also cannot make sense as to why the result would be $d_{j}$. It looks like it is the first component $d_{1}$ in $d \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$.

Can someone help? I am really struggling.

Thanks, Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general fact, if $\vec r, \vec s:\Bbb R \to \Bbb{R}^n$ are vector-valued functions then there is a product rule for dot products which you can easily prove in components:$$\frac{d (\vec r \cdot \vec s)}{dt} = \frac{d\vec r}{dt} \cdot \vec s(t) + \vec r(t) \cdot \frac{d \vec s}{dt}.$$

In your case, $g'(\alpha) = \nabla f(x^* + \alpha \vec d) \cdot \vec d$, where $\vec d$ can be thought of as a constant vector-valued function of $\alpha$, so applying the above we get $$g''(\alpha) = \frac{d \nabla f(x^* + \alpha \vec d)}{d \alpha} \cdot \vec d + \nabla f(x^* + \alpha \vec d) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d \vec d}{d \alpha}}_{0} = \boxed{\frac{d \nabla f(x^* + \alpha \vec d)}{d \alpha} \cdot \vec d}.$$

By the same reasoning as before, and denoting the first partial of $f$ by $f_1$ and so on, $$\frac{d \nabla f(x^* + \alpha \vec d)}{d \alpha} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{d f_1(x^* + \alpha \vec d)}{d\alpha} \\
\frac{d f_2(x^* + \alpha \vec d)}{d\alpha} \\
\vdots
 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} \nabla f_1(x^* + \alpha \vec d) \cdot \vec d \\
\nabla f_2(x^* + \alpha \vec d) \cdot \vec d \\
\vdots
 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^n f_{1j}(x^* + \alpha \vec d) d_j \\
\sum_{j=1}^n f_{2j}(x^* + \alpha \vec d) d_j \\
\vdots
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

so dotting this with $\vec d$ we get $$g''(\alpha)  = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n f_{ij}(x^* + \alpha \vec d)d_j \right)d_i = \sum_{i,j=1}^n f_{ij}(x^* + \alpha \vec d)d_i d_j.$$

Comment: Very very nice! However, I could not follow after $\frac{d \nabla f\left(x^{*}+\alpha \vec{d}\right)}{d \alpha}$ Are you taking the derivative of the gradient vector component wise?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, the derivative of a vector-valued function of a single variable simply amounts to differentiating each component separately.

Comment: After that, why does $\frac{d f_{1}\left(x^{*}+\alpha d\right)}{d \alpha} = \nabla f_{1}\left(x^{*}+\alpha \vec{d}\right) \cdot \vec{d}$?

Comment: @Lucas This is exactly the chain rule that you correctly used yourself to compute $g'(\alpha)$ in your original question, with $f_1$ instead of $f$!

Comment: Thank you very very much! Super detailed answer, exactly what I was looking for! Accepted!